# Animation image Start Bottom to Top

Tags: android, xml, animation

I know my question will take a lot of downvote but someone help me i want to add animation to my `imageview` for example when i click button appears from the bottom and moves up . like this picture

[image]

Comment: See my answer below. I have added working code. Hope this will help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Create `move.xml` that defines the `animation`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

**2.** Create `activity_animation.xml` for showing `Button` and `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_animation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3.** Your `AnimationActivity` should be like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    ImageView imageIcon;
    Button btnStart;

    // Animation
    Animation animMoveToTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

        imageIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        // load the animation
        animMoveToTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);

        // set animation listener
        animMoveToTop.setAnimationListener(this);

        // button click event
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // start the animation
                imageIcon.startAnimation(animMoveToTop);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation
        // check for move animation
        if (animation == animMoveToTop) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~